# How to know whether Text is asserted

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application there is a case where a screen gives 2 types of alerts in 2 scenarios. I need to assert the text in the alert and close the alert.

I have used the following:

```
Alert javascriptAlert= driver.switchTo().alert();
String text= javascriptAlert.getText();
assertTrue(text.matches("Saved Successfully."));
javascriptAlert.accept();
```

Using this I am able to accept the alert. However, even if some other alert is displayed, the alert will be close and it is not shown whether the alert matches the text given.

So how do I find whether the text matches or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a boolean to true if it matches, and use it for your purpose accordingly. Sample method below:

```
public boolean matchAlertTextAndClose(String textToMatch){
    Alert javascriptAlert= driver.switchTo().alert();
    String text= javascriptAlert.getText();
    boolean doesTextMatch = false;
    if(text.matches(textToMatch)){
        doesTextMatch = true;
    }
    else{
        doesTextMatch = false;
    }
    javascriptAlert.accept();
    return doesTextMatch;
}
```

Comment: will it be possible to use and if condition without boolean and test whether it matches or not

Comment: Yes, it sure is. Here boolean variable is set after matching so you don't need it if you have no further execution which is based on the matching. In that case, you can just print something or do whatever you want to do (inside if block, instead of setting boolean). The action totally depends what you want to do after matching.